# Layout conflicting issues

Tags: html, css

So, I have a  and a div which is a result card and a div with a result body/footer. I want the footer to stay in a row on the bottom with a picture on top of results I will find, but I want a rectangular box around it with the result header div text-aligned to the left. I am having some trouble achieving this. I am wondering how I can keep the text aligned to the left while centering it in the middle while keeping the result footer on the bottom of the card as well.

``

```
<section id="restaurant-results">


<div class="result_card">
    <div class="result_header">
        <h2 class="result_title">${title}</h2>
        <h3 class="result_location result_neighborhood">${neighborhood}</h3>
        <h3 class="result_location result_address">${address}</h3>
        <p class="result_price">${price}</p>
        <!--<p>${cuisine type}</p>-->
    </div>

    <div class="result_body">
        <img src="restaurant_photo" class="result_thumbnail" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="result_footer">
        <button class="result_footer_button">Call</button>
        <button class="result_footer_button"><a href="" target="_blank" class="result_website">Visit website</a></button>
        <button class="result_footer_button">Make reservation</button>
    </div>
</div>

</section> 

``
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the style like in that class like this

```
.result_header{
text-align: left
}
```

Or you can set the style inline like this

```
<div class="result_header" style="text-align:left">
```

For result card do this

```
.result_card{
 margin: 0 auto;   
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Add the result card css before the result header css

Comment: but how do i also center the whole result_header ressult body and result footer and have all their margins be the same while having the result_header to the left.

Comment: Answer modified try it out @derek